# How to deal with `Use of undeclared identifier 'UIDevice'`

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, uidevice

I followed the MD file step by step. But there is still an error in the compilation. What can I do?

In the FaceppClient.m file :

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare: @"5.0" options: NSNumericSearch ] != NSOrderedAscending)
    _ios50orNewer = true;
```

Xcode outputs this error :

> Use of undeclared identifier 'UIDevice'

I added `#import "UIDevice.h"` in the file, but Xcode outputs `"UIDevice.h not found"`.

I added the `UIKit` framework to the Project, but I still have the compilation issue.

What can I do then?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try adding this line at the top of your .m file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Adding the framework to the project is useful, but you also have to include the needed headers in your code.

Answer (score 11):

And for Swift 5 users who got here, try

```
import UIKit
```